# Calling an Accessor with a Variable

Tags: java, oop, accessor

I'm practicing my Java skills by making some basic exercises for myself to try out, and I'm trying to make a stupid simple 'text based race game', I guess you could say. The only logic is that whichever car is more powerful wins, and the main point I'm trying to learn here is OOP. I have 4 other classes (Supra, RX7, MX5, and S2000) and call them. In my method 'race' which does all of the logic behind it, I set the car that the user chooses to a variable called 'userCar'. I'm trying to call my getHorsepower() accessor on userCar so I can calculate who would win. My intentions are that if 'userCar' is 'supra', then 'userCar.getHorsepower()' would be the same as 'supra.getHorsepower()'. However, I get an error saying it can't resolve the method getHorsepower() when it's in the if statement. I believe it's because I'm trying to call my accessor on a varaible, and if so, what could I do to fix this? Or it could be a different issue all together.

Thank you,
Nash

Exact Error:
Error:(100, 20) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getHorsepower()
  location: variable userCar of type java.lang.String

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cars{

    private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    private int horsepower;
    private int year;
    private String coo;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Supra supra = new Supra();
        RX7 rx7 = new RX7();
        MX5 mx5 = new MX5();
        S2000 s2000 = new S2000();

        supra.specs();
        rx7.specs();
        mx5.specs();
        s2000.specs();

        System.out.println("Supra: " + supra.getHorsepower() + "HP");
        System.out.println("RX7: " + rx7.getHorsepower() + "HP");
        System.out.println("S2000: " + s2000.getHorsepower() + "HP");
        System.out.println("MX5 (Miata): " + mx5.getHorsepower() + "HP");

        race();
    }

    public void setHorsepower(int h)
    {
        this.horsepower = h;
    }
    public int getHorsepower()
    {
        return horsepower;
    }


    public static void race()
    {
        Supra supra = new Supra();
        RX7 rx7 = new RX7();
        MX5 mx5 = new MX5();
        S2000 s2000 = new S2000();

        supra.specs();
        rx7.specs();
        mx5.specs();
        s2000.specs();

        String userCar = "";
        String compCar = "";

        System.out.println("Choose a car to race");
        System.out.println("1) Supra | 2) RX7 | 3) S2000 | 4) MX5 (Miata)");
        int userChoice = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Choose a car to race against");
        int compChoice = in.nextInt();

        if(userChoice == 1)
            userCar = "supra";
        else if(userChoice == 2)
            userCar = "rx7";
        else if(userChoice == 3)
            userCar = "s2000";
        else if(userChoice == 4)
            userCar = "mx5";

        if(compChoice == 1)
            compCar = "supra";
        else if(compChoice == 2)
            compCar = "rx7";
        else if(compChoice == 3)
            compCar = "s2000";
        else if(compChoice == 4)
            compCar = "mx5";

        if (userCar.getHorsepower() > compCar.getHorsepower())
        {
            System.out.println("You won!");
        } else { System.out.println("That's embarrassing."); }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do Supra, RX7, MX5 and S2000 all extend Car?

Comment: immibis - yes.
Andy - the error I get in the console is: 
Error:(100, 20) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getHorsepower()
  location: variable userCar of type java.lang.String

Comment: It is because you are calling them on java.lang.String, which doesn't have a getHorsepower() method. Like immibis suggests, you need to create a class to represent your car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to use a string as the name of a variable, full stop.

But you can do this instead:

```
    Car userCar = null;

    if(userChoice == 1)
        userCar = supra;
    else if(userChoice == 2)
        userCar = rx7;
    else if(userChoice == 3)
        userCar = s2000;
    else if(userChoice == 4)
        userCar = mx5;
```

And similarly for `compCar`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a term for that, so that I can look more into it?

Comment: A term for what? `userCar` is a variable, `if(...)` is an if statement.

Comment: @NashRead It declares a local variable called `userCar`, of type `Car`, and sets it to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call a method in your `Car` class on an instance of `java.lang.String`. Your `userCar` variable is a String. It should be a `Car` or `Car` subclass.